# Temperature hot receptacle

Tags: electrical

I noticed the area around our floor outlet was warm, so I further inspected the outlet and receptacle. The circular brass faceplate was quite warm. I unplugged our power strip and lamps, and waited 24 hours. The temperature had increased. I turned off the breaker, removed the outlet which was old, and replaced with a new outlet. Hot, neutral, ground wiring - nothing out of the ordinary. The wires and casing appeared intact. I left the breaker off overnight, and the receptacle cooled.

I turned on the breaker, did not plug anything in, and after 24 hours the faceplate and receptacle were again hot to the touch. After turning the breaker back off, I inspected the inside of the receptacle. The wiring was intact. The metal receptacle was the very hot.

My outlet tester says there is not an open ground or neutral, and shows correct wiring. My voltmeter shows 0v when connected to the receptacle and ground. My voltmeter shows 118 when connected to the hot wire and receptacle.

The outlet is in a concrete foundation, and the wires come through a hole in the bottom of the receptacle.

How can this be fixed? Could the problem be elsewhere in the circuit? 1986 house, and the only changes to this circuit have been a ceiling light fixture replacement, and a couple smart switches. All changes were a few years ago, and are working appropriately.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use the backstabs?  Are there other outlets daisy changed to it?

Comment: Did not use backstabs. May be daisy chained to other outlets, but it would have to be the last one. Only one set of wires. Some other outlets in the house are daisy chained.

Comment: for it to be warm/hot, current is passing thrugh the box.  Try a clamp-on.

Comment: "The outlet is in a concrete foundation..." 1. Have you checked if the location is damp, whether from ground water or animals scent-marking? 2. Are there any hot-water or other pipes near the outlet? Check by turning the breaker off -- if the outlet is still hot, it's not from electricity.  3. Is there *another* hot wire coming *out* of the outlet that might carry heavy current?

Comment: Clamp on? Sorry, I'm not familiar.

Comment: No dampness. It's the middle of my living room and there are no other problems with the foundation that I can see. No pipes nearby that I can see. The outlet only gets hot when wired and the outlet works. I've had the wires capped off for the past 24 hrs and it's cold (breaker on). There is no other wires in the receptacle... just the bundle with white/black/ground.